# BLE fixed packet size

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, packet

I would like to know if there is a fixed length packet that exists when establishing a Bluetooth connection.
I know that for Bluetooth 4.0 the PDU length is up to 37byte and is variable。
I want to know if there is such a package whose PDU length is fixed or does not vary much？

Comment: What do you need a fixed size packet for?

Comment: That's a very strange question. Most link layer control packets are of fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what do you mean by package here. The 37 bytes you mentioned is for Advertisement packets. The Specification tells you this way.

> The PDU payloads of these advertising packets can vary in length from
> 6 to 37 octets.

Usually L2CAP PDU size can be upto 64KB(65535 Bytes) to be exact. It depends on application use case to decide what should be the L2CAP PDU size.